# Macos 11.2.3 brew install ffmpeg - where is it?

Tags: mac, ffmpeg, macos-bigsur

I just installed (I think) ffmpeg with:

brew install ffmpeg

on my 11.2.3 iMac.  Seemed  to work, other than an

Error: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /private/tmp/d20210325-18632-lb7ib2

But I can't find the executable anywhere.

Mac-Pro:Cellar user$ which ffmpeg

iMac-Pro:Cellar user$ brew --version
Homebrew 3.0.9
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision cf7b3f4f8d; last commit 2021-03-25)

iMac-Pro:Cellar user$ whereis ffmpeg

iMac-Pro:Cellar user$ brew info ffmpeg

ffmpeg: stable 4.3.2 (bottled), HEAD
Play, record, convert, and stream audio and video
https://ffmpeg.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/ffmpeg.rb
License: GPL-2.0-or-later
==> Dependencies
Build: nasm ✘, pkg-config ✔
Required: aom ✔, dav1d ✔, fontconfig ✔, freetype ✔, frei0r ✔, gnutls ✘, lame ✘, libass ✘, libbluray ✘, libsoxr ✘, libvidstab ✘, libvorbis ✘, libvpx ✘, opencore-amr ✘, openjpeg ✘, opus ✘, rav1e ✘, rubberband ✘, sdl2 ✘, snappy ✘, speex ✘, srt ✘, tesseract ✘, theora ✘, webp ✘, x264 ✘, x265 ✘, xvid ✘, xz ✘, zeromq ✘, zimg ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 169,789 (30 days), 486,799 (90 days), 1,664,084 (365 days)
install-on-request: 143,308 (30 days), 408,501 (90 days), 1,341,197 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)

What am  I missing?

Comment: Your output from `brew info ffmpeg` says `Not installed`.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I fix it?  I've run brew install ffmpeg 2 times.

Comment: Post the whole output from your `brew install ffmpeg` command, in your question.  Also, learn how to format as code, so it will be readable, not all merged together in one line, like the original output you showed.

Comment: Can't post the output as it is too long.

Comment: There is one error:

Comment: Error: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /private/tmp/d20210325-12003-nv9lle

drwx-w--w-  3 user  wheel      96 Mar 25 20:23 d20210325-12003-nv9lle

The directory is new, created by the install ...

Answer (score 0):

So firstly:

> Seemed to work, other than an
> Error: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /private/tmp/d20210325-18632-lb7ib2

Im guessing the the error was the last output from your install command and therefore it is telling you that things actually did not seem to work. And that you package was not installed.

Try this:

```
sudo chown -R <your-user-name>:wheel /private/tmp
```

Comment: I don’t see how this is supposed to fix the issue. The error is not a permission error at all.